# Filter mongodb documents by Guid field with Regex startswith

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have part of GUID like `6767a567` (first 32 bytes).
I need find mongodb document. He has identificator like `6767a567-1d6b-4360-b6b5-a5e100cc5c68`.

I tried to filter with regex

```cs
var listFilters = new List<FilterDefinition<Document>>();
var regex = new BsonRegularExpression($"^6767a567", "i");
listFilters.Add(Builders<Document>.Filter.Regex(t => t.Id, regex));
var entities = await Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Same i try to make query to bd like

```
{ "_id" : { "$regex" : /.*/ } }
```

It's return empty. I expect to find my document, but it returns empty list.